# iOS 8 CoreBluetooth deprecated RSSI methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-bluetooth

So from reading the `CBPeripheralDelegate` documentation, it appears that `RSSI` and `peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:error:` were deprecated with iOS 8.

Xcode warning:

> 'rssi' was deprecated in iOS 8.0

I noticed that my signal strength indicator was no longer being updated, so I did some research and found a new method (`[CBPeripheralDelegate peripheral:didReadRSSI:error:]`) that supposedly get called back asynchronously after calling the `readRSSI` method. Unfortunately, this method does not seem to get called back either, even though I did set the parent class as the CBPeripheral delegate.

Has anyone else had issues with the iOS 8 CoreBluetooth updates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a known issue that has been posted about this on the Apple Developer forums to which I have an open radar as well.

The issue seems to be that the new callback method `peripheral:didReadRSSI:error:` is never called on iOS 8 specifically after the initial connection is made to a peripheral. The only resolution I have found is to reset bluetooth on your phone by turning it on/off or restarting the phone.

[Here is the link to open radar I filed.](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6677108495482880)

## UPDATE:

Just tested my example that was displaying this issue with the current 8.2 release and I am no longer seeing any issues with the new iOS 8 delegate method never being called. I am marking my radar as resolved per the 8.2 release.

Comment: Seeing the exact same issue on iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: I've been testing each beta release and the next upcoming release seems to have this issue resolved.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 8.1.1, `peripheral:didReadRSSI:error:` will only get called for peripherals that you are connected to. If you've merely discovered the peripherals with a scan and then called `readRSSI` on them, the callback will not be called.

Try connecting to the peripheral first (via `CBCentralManager`'s `connectPeripheral:options:`), and then calling `readRSSI`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Actually it does provide an answer to the question. His question involved `peripheral:didReadRSSI:error:` not getting called and he asked if anyone else had issues with it. I did have issues with it and I found the solution to making CoreBluetooth call that delegate method in iOS 8: connect to the peripheral.

Comment: This will only return successfully the first time you connect to the peripheral and call [peripheral readRSSI]. Any subsequent connections will fail to call the didReadRSSI delegate method.

Comment: @Shree: This is actually the only way to periodically refresh RSSI of observed-but-not-connected-to peripherals. Though it does not answer the question per-se it provides a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It works iOS 8.0.2, but it is throttled now. I send a readRSSI every 200ms and get a response only once a second. It worked fine with iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

It works again in iOS 8.0.2!

use `[myPeripheral readRSSI];`