# How to get RSSI in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, core-bluetooth

I have BLE source code that displays several warnings and I am new to
BLE. Please see the code below. I have tried replacing with readRSSI but tells me I can’t compare an Int with Void. How do I get an Int value for readRSSI? Or how should I change the code?

```
- (void)peripheralDidUpdateRSSI:(CBPeripheral * _Nonnull)peripheral error:(NSError * _Nullable)error
{
    if (!isConnected)
        return;
    if (rssi != peripheral.RSSI.intValue)
    {
        rssi = peripheral.RSSI.intValue;
        [[self delegate] bleDidUpdateRSSI:activePeripheral.RSSI];
    }
}
```

*rssi is a static int.

*isConnected is a boolean.

Edit: The problem is that RSSI is deprecated since iOS 8.0.

Comment: static int of rssi cage to NSNumber *rssi = peripheral.RSSI;

Comment: u tried ... what the issue ur facing ..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 8 CoreBluetooth deprecated RSSI methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952218/ios-8-corebluetooth-deprecated-rssi-methods)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of obtaining the `CBPeripheral`'s RSSI.  The first is when the peripheral is discovered.  You will get a call to the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` method

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, 
             didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
       advertisementData: [String : Any], 
                    rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    let rssi = intValue
    ...
}
```

If you are running in the foreground then you can supply a value of `true` to for the key `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` in the scanning options to get repeated calls to `didDiscover`. This doesn't work in the background.

If you are connected to a peripheral then you can periodically call `peripheral.readRSSI()`.  This will result in a callback to the `didReadRSSI` `CBPeripheralDelegate` method:

```
optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
         didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, 
               error: Error?) {
    let rssi = RSSI.intValue
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
@IBAction func btnGetRSSI(_ sender: UIButton){

    self.selectedPeripehral.readRSSI() 
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {

    var rssiInt: Int!

    rssiInt = RSSI.intValue

}
```